# Storybook react-native error in while running on windows not able to make proper stories.require.js file

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon, storybook-addon-specifications, nextjs-storybook, storybook-addon-doc

I have implemented the storybook(v 6.5) in react-native in my root project
when i run the script to run storybook on my device which is andriod and ios
the file which is created IN `.ondevice` folder is `story.require.js`    is have path issue in windows system it is proper in linux and mac but i am getting the error in windows

this is the file which created in windows system `story.require.js`

```
import {
  configure,
  addDecorator,
  addParameters,
  addArgsEnhancer,
  clearDecorators,
} from "@storybook/react-native";
global.STORIES = [
  {
    titlePrefix: "",
    directory: "./src/components",
    files: "**/*.stories.?(ts|tsx|js|jsx)",
    importPathMatcher:
      "^\\.[\\\\/](?:src[\\\\/]components(?:[\\\\/](?!\\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:^|[\\\\/])\\.).)*?)[\\\\/]|[\\\\/]|$)(?!\\.)(?=.)[^\\\\/]*?\\.stories\\.(?:ts|tsx|js|jsx)?)$",
  },
];
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions/register";
import { argsEnhancers } from "@storybook/addon-actions/dist/modern/preset/addArgs";
import { decorators, parameters } from "./preview";
if (decorators) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    // stops the warning from showing on every HMR
    require("react-native").LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      "clearDecorators is deprecated and will be removed in Storybook 7.0",
    ]);
  }
  // workaround for global decorators getting infinitely applied on HMR, see https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/185
  clearDecorators();
  decorators.forEach((decorator) => addDecorator(decorator));
}
if (parameters) {
  addParameters(parameters);
}
try {
  argsEnhancers.forEach((enhancer) => addArgsEnhancer(enhancer));
} catch {}
const getStories = () => {
  return {
    "./srccomponentsCustomButtonCustomButton.stories.tsx": require("..srccomponentsCustomButtonCustomButton.stories.tsx"),
    "./srccomponentsCustomCheckBoxCustomCheckBox.stories.tsx": require("..srccomponentsCustomCheckBoxCustomCheckBox.stories.tsx"),
    "./srccomponentsCustomTextCustomText.stories.tsx": require("..srccomponentsCustomTextCustomText.stories.tsx"),
  };
};
configure(getStories, module, false);
```

the file which is correctly created in linux and mac is this

is there any solution for the forword \ backword / issue that is being created with the storybook
for the .ondevice  folder

I have tried the path.resolve() and replace is not working

```
import {
  configure,
  addDecorator,
  addParameters,
  addArgsEnhancer,
  clearDecorators,
} from "@storybook/react-native";

global.STORIES = [
  {
    titlePrefix: "",
    directory: "./src/components",
    files: "**/*.stories.?(ts|tsx|js|jsx)",
    importPathMatcher:
      "^\\.[\\\\/](?:src\\/components(?:\\/(?!\\.)(?:(?:(?!(?:^|\\/)\\.).)*?)\\/|\\/|$)(?!\\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\\.stories\\.(?:ts|tsx|js|jsx)?)$",
  },
];

import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds/register";
import "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions/register";
import { argsEnhancers } from "@storybook/addon-actions/dist/modern/preset/addArgs";
import { decorators, parameters } from "./preview";

if (decorators) {
  if (__DEV__) {
    // stops the warning from showing on every HMR
    require("react-native").LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      "clearDecorators is deprecated and will be removed in Storybook 7.0",
    ]);
  }
  // workaround for global decorators getting infinitely applied on HMR, see https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native/issues/185
  clearDecorators();
  decorators.forEach((decorator) => addDecorator(decorator));
}

if (parameters) {
  addParameters(parameters);
}

try {
  argsEnhancers.forEach((enhancer) => addArgsEnhancer(enhancer));
} catch {}

const getStories = () => {
  return {
    "./src/components/CustomText/CustomText.stories.tsx": require("../src/components/CustomText/CustomText.stories.tsx"),
  };
};

configure(getStories, module, false);
```

please provide some idea to reolve the path issue in the windows